# Slicing a multidimensional list

Tags: python, list, slice

I have a variable length multi-dimensional like the following:

```
listD = [[[[53, 54], [129, 130]]], 
     [[[51, 51], [132, 132]]], 
     [[[39, 39], 
       [144, 144]], 
      [[53, 54], 
       [129, 130]]], 
     [[[39, 39], [146, 146]], [[54, 54], [130, 130]]], 
     [[[54, 53], [130, 129]]], 
     [[[52, 52], [132, 132]]]
    ]
```

I need to pick out the first element in each of the innermost of the lists. The output should look like this:

```
outlist=[[[[53, 54]]], 
     [[[51, 51]]], 
     [[[39, 39]], 
      [[53, 54]]], 
     [[[39, 39]], 
      [[54, 54]]], 
     [[[54, 53]]], 
     [[[52, 52]]]
    ]
```

I am trying to slice using 0 and :s, I am not getting the right list back. How to do this in python?

I had made an error in my out list. I have edited the list. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: please show what have you done so far.

Comment: If you want to avoid list comprehension, you may want to look into numpy...

Comment: I would like to use list comprehension. Thus far, I tried to use
`outlist = [listD[n][:,0,:] for n in range(8)]` after converting the list to array. This gives me a type error that I am using a tuple instead of an integer for index. The error makes sense, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Are you using numpy?

Comment: @RameshRamasubramanian, why the output has deep nested lists, don't you want to get simple list of lists like `[[53, 54], [51, 51], ...]` ?

Comment: In your question, `len(listD) == 7` and `len(outlist) == 6`, is this intentional?

Comment: Are you sure the second-to-last row is supposed to be `[[[54, 53], [130, 129]]], [[[52, 52], [132, 132]]], ` rather than `[[[54, 53], [130, 129]], [[52, 52], [132, 132]]], `?

Comment: Look at the itertools library (builtin lib) @RameshRamasubramanian

Comment: @Billy, my mistake. I did not format my output correctly. I edited the list and the output.

Comment: Okay, but now your `outlist` is 5 elements long and your `listD` is 6.

Comment: @Billy, I think I have corrected the output. Both should be 6 long

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, I can't use a flat list as my next operation is to get the index of the item within the sublist that will satisfy a condition

Answer (score 3):

Try with nested list comprehension:

```
[[[x[0]] for x in y] for y in listD]
```

---

**In steps:**

Look at each nested row in your `listD` and see how it corresponds to `outlist`.  You can see that the first element of each of the 1-deep list is included in `outlist`

```
>>> [x[0] for x in listD[0]] 
[[53, 54]]
>>> [x[0] for x in listD[1]] 
[[51, 51]]
>>> [x[0] for x in listD[2]] 
[[39, 39], [53, 54]]
```

But in `outlist`, these lists are then nested in one more 1-element list, so wrap each one of these into it's own list, e.g the next element would be:

```
>>> [[x[0] for x in listD[3]]]
[[[39, 39], [54, 54]]]
```

then extend it for each index of `listD`:

```
[[[x[0]] for x in listD[i]] for i in range(len(listD))]
```

then simplify further by replacing `listD[i]` with just the elements of `listD`:

```
[[[x[0]] for x in y] for y in listD]
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  Given the `listD` in the question, this answer gives the exact `outlist`...

Comment: Not sure who is down voting this, this does help me a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear whether your list of lists has uniform depth or not. If it is variable depth, you are best approaching this recursively.

Given:

```
>>> listD = [[[[53, 54], [129, 130]]], 
...      [[[51, 51], [132, 132]]], 
...      [[[39, 39], 
...      [144, 144]], 
...     [[53, 54], 
...      [129, 130]]], 
...      [[[39, 39], [146, 146]], [[54, 54], [130, 130]]], 
...      [[[54, 53], [130, 129]]], 
...      [[[52, 52], [132, 132]]]
...     ]
>>> 
>>> outlist=[[[[53, 54]]], 
...      [[[51, 51]]], 
...      [[[39, 39]], 
...     [[53, 54]]], 
...      [[[39, 39]], 
...     [[54, 54]]], 
...      [[[54, 53]]], 
...      [[[52, 52]]]
...     ]
```

You can recursively traverse the list of lists until you find a list that has no lists in the first element. Keep that. Otherwise, increase the nesting.

Example:

```
def trav(x):
    result = []
    for el in x:
        if isinstance(el, list) and any(isinstance(e, list) for e in el[0]):
            result.append(trav(el))
        else:
            result.append([el[0]])
    return result


>>> trav(listD)
[[[[53, 54]]], [[[51, 51]]], [[[39, 39]], [[53, 54]]], [[[39, 39]], 
[[54, 54]]], [[[54, 53]]], [[[52, 52]]]]
>>> trav(listD)==outlist
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a flattening function I made recently that accepts an arbitrary number of dimensions:

```py
def get_dims(data):
    if not isinstance(data, (list, tuple)):
        return 0
    return get_dims(data[0]) + 1
def flatten(data, depth = 0):
    if get_dims(data) == depth:
        return [data]
    elif get_dims(data) == depth + 1:
        return list(data)
    return sum([flatten(v, depth) for v in data], [])
```

The `depth` parameter is for leaving a few sublists if the user wishes. This is useful below:

```py
print([x[0] for x in flatten(listD, 1)])
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use:

```
temp=[item for sublist in listD for item in sublist]
flatten=[item for sublist in temp for item in sublist]    
[flatten[int(i*2)] for i in xrange(int(len(flatten)/2))]
```

to get:

```
  [[53, 54],
 [51, 51],
 [39, 39],
 [53, 54],
 [39, 39],
 [54, 54],
 [54, 53],
 [52, 52]]
```

or:

```
[[[flatten[int(i*2)]]] for i in xrange(int(len(flatten)/2))]
```

to get it nested like you wrote.

Comment: flattened list does not work as my subsequent operation has to get index of particular item is the in side list. The list is highly variable, the inside list may be 2 or 3 or 5 or n long.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
res_list = []

for item in listD:
    sub_list = []
    for i in item:
        sub_list.append([i[0]])
    res_list.append(sub_list)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> res_list
[[[[53, 54]]], [[[51, 51]]], [[[39, 39]], [[53, 54]]], [[[39, 39]], [[54, 54]]], [[[54, 53]]], [[[52, 52]]]]
```

With list comprehension, you can try:

```
res_list = [[[i[0]] for i in item] for item in listD]
```