# Is it possible to slice multidimensional LISTS (not numpy) in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, slice

This question is the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277100/python-slicing-a-multi-dimensional-array), but for native python lists.

Assume the following:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ones((5, 6, 7))
a_list = a.tolist()
```

I can slice `a` like so:

```
a_slice = a[2:4, 4:, :3]
```

Is the same possible in some way for `a_list`?

---

The reason for asking is I am getting a stream of nested lists like `a_list`, and only want to save a slice of the stream for later use.
I wouldn't want to go through a numpy array for this, because it would allocate the memory each time, which is very sub-optimal.
I am looking for a way to accomplish that.

---

EDIT for shivam_Jha

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ones((5, 6, 7))
a_list = a.tolist()
a_list
Out[20]: 
[[[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
 [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
 [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
 [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],
 [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]]
```

Expecting an output

```
a[2:4, 4:, :3].tolist()
Out[21]: [[[1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]], [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]]
```

Comment: Can you give an example, by taking a list, and showing your expected output , please?

Comment: With a very not nice list comprehension yes, something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40852575/slicing-a-multidimensional-list

Comment: All the answers you'll get will be some version of nested list comprehensions.

Comment: There is no `numpy` like multi dimensional indexing in raw python. Therefore you would have to access the list dimension after dimension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [65]: a = np.ones((5,6,7),int)
In [66]: alist = a.tolist()
In [67]: len(alist)
Out[67]: 5
In [68]: a[2:4, 4:, :3].shape
Out[68]: (2, 2, 3)
In [69]: np.array(alist[2:4]).shape
Out[69]: (2, 6, 7)
In [70]: np.array([a1 for a1 in alist[2:4]]).shape
Out[70]: (2, 6, 7)
In [71]: np.array([a1[4:] for a1 in alist[2:4]]).shape
Out[71]: (2, 2, 7)
In [72]: np.array([[a2[:3] for a2 in a1[4:]] for a1 in alist[2:4]]).shape
Out[72]: (2, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
listD = [
    [
        [
            [53, 54], [129, 130]
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            [51, 51], [132, 132]
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            [39, 39], [144, 144]
        ],
        [
            [53, 54], [129, 130]
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            [39, 39], [146, 146]
        ],
        [
            [54, 54], [130, 130]
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            [54, 53], [130, 129]
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            [52, 52], [132, 132]
        ]
    ]
]

newList = [[item[0]] for sub_list in listD for item in sub_list]

print(newList)
```

Output:
`[[[53, 54]], [[51, 51]], [[39, 39]], [[53, 54]], [[39, 39]], [[54, 54]], [[54, 53]], [[52, 52]]]`

if you do like this:
`newList = [item[0] for sub_list in listD for item in sub_list]`
It gives me:
`[[53, 54], [51, 51], [39, 39], [53, 54], [39, 39], [54, 54], [54, 53], [52, 52]]`

Comment: copy pasting other answers is frowned upon. This doesn't answer the question, doesn't give credit, and is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Hey, I tried my own logic, it is a co-incidence that the answers matched.
I formatted the list, inspected it and then wrote code and also wrote the output.
If you wish, I can explain the logic to you.